# How to change the default index.html file in titanium mobile web?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I would like to know how to change the default `index.html` file. I have created a classic project (for mobile web). In that I have created a `.css` file which includes my custom styles. Now I would like to include this file in index.html, so that those styles will apply on my application. But haven't seen the `index.html` file. After build, I am able to see this file in build folder. May I know how to update the `index.html` file?

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator uses XML for views, TSS for styling, and JS for controllers.  Then Titanium compiles your source code into the native API (HTML for mobile web).  Because you can also compile for iOS, Android, and Windows, your output is converted appropriately to your build directory.  When you create a new Alloy project, you will find the default index.xml, index.tss, and index.js in the app views, styles, and controllers directories respectively.  So to control index.html, edit these 3 index.* files.